# "I haven't seen him lately" 我最近没有看到他 is 有 necessary?

Tags: translation

I'm trying to say `I haven't seen him lately`, I got two versions:

- `我最近没有看到他`
- `我最近没看到他`

My question is are they both correct and mean the same thing? Is it like in this case with `有` the `看到` is more like a noun, but without `有` the `看到` is more like a verb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- 没有 means 'did not/ have not' when followed by a verb. e.g. 昨天没有上學 (Didn't go to school yesterday)
- 没有 means 'do not have' when followed by a noun.  e.g. 我没有錢 (I don't have money)

In either case, 有 can be omitted without changing the meaning of the sentence

昨天没有上學 --> 昨天没上學

我没有錢 --> 我没錢

Omitting the 有 in 没有 makes the sentence sounds more direct(blunt) and colloquial and less formal

> 我最近没有看到他 is 有 necessary?

It depends.

我最近**没有**看到他(more emphasis on the negative aspect)

我最近**没看到**他 (more colloquial)

我没有偷你的錢 sounds stronger as a denial than 我没偷你錢

Answer (score 1):

> 我最近没有看到他 // It somehow implies that I have been searched for him, but I failed. Or, if I have had seen him, I would probably have done something.

> 我最近没看到他 // It says that I just haven't seen him (for no reasons). It's just a fact.

The nuance might not be that important, in practice you could probably use them interchangeably most of time I guess.